# shell dynamically answer to terminal prompt

Tags: regex, command-line, expect

#### questions.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a animals=("dog" "cat")
declare -a num=("1" "2" "3")

for a in "${animals[@]}"
do
    for n in "${num[@]}"
    do
        echo "$n $a ?"
        read REPLY
        echo "Your answer is: $REPLY"
    done
done
```

#### responder.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f

set timeout -1

spawn ./questions.sh

while true {

    expect {
        "*dog*" { send -- "bark\r" }

        "^((?!dog).)*$" { send -- "mew\r" }
    }


}

expect eof
```

### running: './responder.sh'

#### expected outcome:

```
1 dog ?
bark
Your answer is: bark
2 dog ?
bark
Your answer is: bark
3 dog ?
bark
Your answer is: bark
1 cat ?
mew
Your answer is: mew
2 cat ?
mew
Your answer is: mew
3 cat ?
mew
Your answer is: mew
```

#### actual outcome: hang at 'cat' question and not responding...

```
1 dog ?
bark
Your answer is: bark
2 dog ?
bark
Your answer is: bark
3 dog ?
bark
Your answer is: bark
1 cat ?
```

tried and searched multiple ways but still not working. thank you very much.

Comment: You're mixing regex and glob syntax -- they can't both be right. That is to say, either `*dog*` is the syntax that expect uses to match (fnmatch-style glob), or `^((?!dog).)*$` is (regex with negative assertions first pioneered in Perl/PCRE extended syntax); they can't both be right. Or it could be a different regex syntax that doesn't support `(?!...)` at all, which actually strikes me as more likely knowing `expect`'s origins.

Comment: ...that said, insofar as your shell program works fine and it's only your expect program (expect being a TCL derivative, not a shell-family language itself) that malfunctions, I'd suggest taking out the `bash` and `shell` tags and focusing this on the `expect` tag, which is where people who can actually answer this question will live.

Comment: thank you @CharlesDuffy I'll remove bash/shell tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expect program hangs because you match the first "dog", send bark, then you `expect eof` with an infinite timeout. Of course you don't have "eof" because the shell script is waiting for input.

You need to use the `exp_continue` command for your loops, not `while`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set timeout -1
spawn ./questions.sh
expect {
    -re {dog \?\r\n$}        { send -- "bark\r"; exp_continue }
    -re {(?!dog)\S+ \?\r\n$}  { send -- "mew\r";  exp_continue }
    eof
}
```

I made the patterns much more specific: either "dog" or "not dog" followed by a space, question mark and end-of-line characters.

The `exp_continue` commands will keep the code looping within the expect command until "eof" is encountered.

---

We can make the pattern a little DRYer:

```
expect {
    -re {(\S+) \?\r\n$} { 
        if {$expect_out(1,string) eq "dog"} then {send "bark\r"} else {send "mew\r"} 
        exp_continue 
    }
    eof
}
```

Comment: gave it a try just now, and working perfectly. thank you so much!